# Cannot subtract one value from another (unsigned)

Tags: mysql, sql, integer, unsigned

I have a table `stats` with three columns:

- `id`
- `up` - number of upvotes (just like here at StackOverflow)
- `down` - analogue to `up`

`up` and `down` are `INT(11)` and `UNSIGNED` (because they'll only be positive values).

Now when I want to fetch the ten items with the highest `(up-down)` value, I'm using this query:

```
SELECT id, up, down, (up-down) AS result
FROM stats
ORDER BY result DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

But I'm getting an error

```
#1690 - BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in
        '(`database`.`stats`.`up` - `database`.`stats`.`down`)'
```

If I leave out the `ORDER BY result DESC` everything runs smoothly (except for the fact that they're not ordered by `result`, but the math of `up-down` is working).

What would I have to change in my query in order to retreive the correct result? Or do I have to remove the `UNSIGNED` attribute? But isn't this an appropriate case where I should use that attribute?

Comment: is the result of (up-down) a positive integer always? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html

Comment: You might run a test with `cast(up as int) - cast(down as int)` (and order by the same expression) to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Consider to change the type to BIGINT (SIGNED). You've got to cast to signed anyway and the range should be sufficient too.

Comment: @SlimsGhost Would you not run into trouble casting when the ints approach their limit? Better to change the column type to signed as VMai said.

Comment: @Arth Well 9223372036854775807 is a long way to go to reach the limit for upvotes or downvotes, don't you think so too?

Comment: @VMai I do but the OP suggests an unsigned int.. which has a lower limit. But even if you'll never hit the limit; I hate the idea of having a query that isn't going to return the correct result on perfectly valid data in the table.

Comment: @Arth INT should be sufficient too, I imagine. And yes, I hate that too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unsigned remain unsigned, so you have a problem when the result would be negative.  Cast to signed before the subtraction:

```
SELECT id, up, down, cast(up as signed) - cast(down as signed) AS result
FROM stats
ORDER BY result DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Or, keep your query and add a `where` clause:

```
SELECT id, up, down, (up-down) AS result
FROM stats
WHERE up >= down
ORDER BY result DESC
LIMIT 0,10;
```

Comment: Great thanks. The first query helped, the second not so much as `down` can generally greater than `up`.